# PivotFields Collection

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to:

1. Copy the PivotTable.PivotFields Collection Object to a temporary
   one
2. Perform some changes on the temporary one,
3. Then set the original PivotTable.PivotFields Collection to point to
   the new PivotFields Collection.

I'm trying to use the following code. I get a Compile error on the indicated line when I try to use "New PivotFields". What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appriciated.

```
Public Sub ChangePivotTable()

    Dim objPivotTable As PivotTable
    Dim objPivotFields As PivotFields
    Dim objTempPivotFields As PivotFields

    'Get Pivot Table from worksheet
    Set objPivotTable = Worksheets("PivotTableWorksheet").PivotTables(1)
    'Set reference to PivotFields Collection of PivotTable
    Set objPivotFields = objPivotTable.PivotFields

    'Compile error: Invalid use of New Keyword
    Set objTempPivotFields = New PivotFields

    'Pass Collection by Value
    Let objTempPivotFields = objPivotFields 

    'Make changes to Temporary PivotFields Collection
    Dim intIndex As Integer
    For intIndex = 6 To 2156

        objTempPivotFields(intIndex).Orientation = xlDataField
        objTempPivotFields(intIndex).Function = xlAverage

    Next intIndex

    'Set original PivotFields Collection to temporary one
    Set objPivotFields = objTempPivotFields

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just make the changes to the current pivot fields?

Comment: Because, I have upwards of 2100 Fields in the table. The code I'm using currently changes the Orintation and Function properties on the original PivotField. This triggers the entire pivot table to recalculate every time. It's taking hours due to the amount of data.

Comment: Here's a post on turning off recalculation: http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/speeding-up-pivottable-updates/. I'm 99.5% sure you can't swap a whole set of fields in and out like you are trying.

Comment: I tried clicking the "Defer Layout Update" checkbox, but it gave errors then when I tried setting the Orientation property. I was not aware that there was a seperate way using VBA. I'll try it tomorrow. Thanks Doug.

Comment: @DougGlancy: I think you should give your comment as an answer (i was about to write the same until I saw your comment) ;-)